# requests.post makes a get request

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I call requests.post but it ends up making a GET request.

```
post_body="""
{
...
}
"""
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
post_response = requests.post("https://...", data=post_body, headers=headers)
print(post_response.request.method)
```

The last print statement prints "GET". I expected to see "POST".

To debug this further, I changed the code like so:

```
req = requests.Request('POST', "https://...", data=booking_body, headers=headers)
prepared = req.prepare
print(prepared.method) // "POST"
s = requests.Session()
post_response = s.send(prepared)
print(post_response.request.method) // "GET"
```

The print statements print "POST" and "GET". What am I doing wrong?

PS:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.0
```

Comment: Is there a redirect in the POST? Maybe the redirect is made with GET instead of POST.

Comment: That was it. I was actually making a call to "http://.." which was being redirected to "https://...". Once I made the call to "https://...", the issue was resolved. Happy to accept this as an answer if posted as one.

Comment: I posted an answer, happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the issue was in redirect. The call was initially been made to `http://...` then redirected to `https://...`. Hence, the last method was `GET`.

Once the initial call was made to `https://...`, the issue was resolved.